# Definir el color del texto, segun el color de fondo con Sass

Tags: css, sass, scss, preprocesador

necesito ayuda, y saber si se puede o no hacer lo siguiente.

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Sass (SCSS), y estoy intentando hacer que el texto de un boton cambie, de acuerdo al color de fondo.

La idea es que si el color de fondo es un color oscuro, el color del texto sea un color claro, en su defecto blanco, y si  el color de fondo es claro, el color del texto sea un color oscuro, en su defecto negro.

Hasta el momento tengo este codigo, pero no se si lo estoy haciendo mal, por que el Sass si se esta compilando sin generar ninguna error, pero no se reflejan los cambios.

```
$colors: black, white, blue, red, green, yellow, orange;

@each $color in $colors {
  .btn-#{$color} {
    background: $color;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    @if $color == lighten {
      color: #000;
    } @else {
      color: #fff;
    }
  }
}
```

Estoy usando un ciclo `@each` y una condicional `@if`.

Alguien me puede confirmar o ayudar ?.

Comment: Bueno en ese caso, si te fijas la variable `$color`, recorre una lista de elementos llamada `$colors` con una iteracion `@each` de Sass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que jugar un poco con las opciones de [sass:color](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color).

Una opción es leer el [lightness](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#lightness) del color y a partir de eso devolver una cosa u otra:

```
@function color-texto($color) {
  @if (lightness($color) > 50) {
    @return black;
  } @else {
    @return white;
  }
}

$colors: black, white, blue, red, green, yellow, orange;

@each $color in $colors {
  .btn-#{$color} {
    background: $color;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: color-texto($color);
  }
}
```

Comment: Excelente, compa, no lo había pensado, pero me funciono, muchas gracias.